# Add method to rails model without restarting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

i am currently struggling with fixing an error in my rails application. Is it possible to add a method to a rails model. I have to admit that my rails skills are really basic.

An example:
My observations_controller.rb is calling

```
:trainingObs => observation_from_twitter.map { |o| { :category => o.rejected ? Do_something : Do_something_else}}
```

where observation_from_twitter is an array of observation objects. But unfortunately i still have to implement the method `rejected`. How do i now apply the change after adding the method to the model? And is that possible without restarting the server as stated in the title?

Thanks

Comment: In production mode, by default, you don't have code reloading.

Comment: So would it be sufficient to restart the server? Or how do i normally deploy small changes into production?

Comment: you should talk to your senior to roll out a new fixed build